# sort function only activates after second change event

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have a function that is supposed to sort a list with objects alphabetically, depending if clicked on ascending or descending (a select with 2 options)
The problem is that when I change the value the first time, nothing happens, it only activates after the second change.

Here's my code:

```
function modulesSorter(a, b) {
  let moduleName1 = a.module.toLowerCase();
  let moduleName2 = b.module.toLowerCase();
  let place = 0
  if (value === "descending" || value == null) {
    if (moduleName1 > moduleName2) {
      place = 1
    } else if (moduleName1 < moduleName2) {
      place = -1
    }
  } else if (value === "ascending") {
    if (moduleName1 > moduleName2) {
      place = -1
    } else if (moduleName1 < moduleName2) {
      place = 1
    }
  }
  return place;
}
let value

function changeFilter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  renderModules(modules.sort(modulesSorter));
  value = document.querySelector('#sortby').value;
  console.log(value)
}
```

I also activate the function once in the init so that it is sorted ascending as that is the default value.

Comment: Which value are you changing?

Comment: `value` has no value at the time you're calling the function for the first time, move the function call to the end of the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible the "first" attempt sorts the objects into the same order they are current in.

The reason you see the effect you describe, is because during the first run `value` is undefined until *after* the sorting algorithm runs:

```js
function changeFilter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  renderModules(modules.sort(modulesSorter));
  value = document.querySelector('#sortby').value;
  console.log(value)
}
```

Change the order of those two statements like this:

```js
function changeFilter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  value = document.querySelector('#sortby').value;
  renderModules(modules.sort(modulesSorter));
  console.log(value)
}
```